# Drawing multiple lines perpendicular on an ellipse (i.e. "eyelashes") using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw a complicated function and have tried multiple things but TikZ won't let me. I'm probably doing something wrong very stupidly.

Anyway I want to draw "eyelashes" on this ellipse. That is I want to draw little lines from the border of the ellipse outwards (wrt the centre of the ellipse) like so:

[image]

or rather

[image]

If my math is correct we can define this ellipse using

Given a point (x,y) on the ellipse we can define a new point (x<sup>*</sup>, y<sup>*</sup>) using

[image]

But for the life of me I can't seem to get it working. I'd like to have the eyelashes on the points x at {-1, 0, ..., 5} but ultimately I want to add as much as possible (i.e. I should be able to put in the number of eyelashes) I want to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{StackOverflow help example}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[step=1cm, gray!50!white, very thin] (-2,-2) grid (6,6); % <bottom left> grid <top right>
\draw (2,2) circle (3cm and 1cm); % draw ellipse
% This doesn't work 
%\foreach \x in {-1, -0.5, ..., 5}
    % \draw[red] ({\x},{2+sqrt(1-(\x-2)^2/9)}) -- ({\x+cos(asin(deg((2+sqrt(1-(\x-2)^2/9)-2)/(\x-2))))},{2+sqrt(1-(\x-2)^2/9)});

\draw[thick,->] (-2,-2) -- (6,-2) node[anchor=west]{x}; % draw x axis. anchor west means that x attaches to the east
\draw[thick,->] (-2,-2) -- (-2,6) node[anchor=south]{y}; % draw y axis. anchor east means that y attached to the west 

\foreach \x in {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    \draw (\x cm, -2) -- (\x cm, -2.1) node[anchor=north]{$\x$}; 
\foreach \y in {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    \draw (-2, \y cm) -- (-2.1, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{$\y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm confused by the uppermost figure (which you drew by hand). Do you want the eyelashes to be orthogonal to a tangent to the ellipsis, or, as indicated in the figure, to point to the center (or is that a focal point where the axes cross)?

Comment: They should be tangent to the ellips (or if you continue the line they should cross the centre of the ellips). Sorry if my drawing was unclear. (edit: Is this not the same? Take a circle then any line extending from its origin is orthogonal to the tangent at the point it crosses. I thought this also held for an ellips or am I wrong here?)

Comment: It's false for an ellipse which is not a circle. Should your ‘eyelashes’ point to the centre or be normal to the ellipse?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. They should be tangent to the ellips.

Comment: I suggest to change the title of your question in such a way that others who might have a similar problem have better chances of finding it. Maybe something like ``Drawing an ellipse with eyelashes in tikz'' is more appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not think that the eyelashes point to the center, but they do for the circle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\mya{6}\def\myb{3}
\begin{document}
An ellipse can be parametrized by
\[ \gamma(t)~=~(a\,\cos t,b\,\sin t)\;.\]
The tangent to this curve is hence
\[ \dot\gamma(t)~=~(-a\,\sin t,b\,\cos t)\;.\]
The normalizaed eylashes, which are orthogonal to the tangent, point hence to
\[ \omega(t)~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2\,\cos^2 t+a^2\sin^2 t}}(b\,\cos t,a\,\sin t)\;.\]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse ({\mya cm} and {\myb cm});
\foreach \x in {0,10,...,180} 
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\mya*cos(\x)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\myb*sin(\x)} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myu}{\myx+0.2*\myb*cos(\x)/(sqrt(pow(\myb,2)*pow(cos(\x),2)+pow(\mya,2)*pow(sin(\x),2)))} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myv}{\myy+0.2*\mya*sin(\x)/(sqrt(pow(\myb,2)*pow(cos(\x),2)+pow(\mya,2)*pow(sin(\x),2)))} 
    \draw[blue] (\myx,\myy) -- (\myu,\myv);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make the eyelashes longer or shorter by changing the `0.2` in the macros for `\myu` and `\myv`.

Or you can use decorations by finding a point on the ellipse and then using an arc:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\def\mya{6}\def\myb{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse ({\mya cm} and {\myb cm});
\draw[decoration={ticks,% name of the decoration
        raise=5pt,% offset from the original path
        amplitude=5pt,% half-length of each tick
        segment length=5mm},% distance between consecutive ticks
        decorate,red,ultra thick] 
    ({\mya*cos(135)},{\myb*sin(135)}) arc (135:20:\mya{}  and \myb);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I just started learning TikZ today so thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I'm not 100 % sure if I understand your question, but if you mean that you want to parametrize the ellipse by the length of the curve `s` instead of `t`, and set the eyelashes at equidistant `s` values, the answer is certainly yes.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Well, I have outlined how this can be done. However, I have problems implementing this because I do not know which functions are known to pgf. Do you have a list of functions known to pgf?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I asked the corresponding question, but the relevant function (known as EllipticE in Mathematica) is not known in pgf. If I use a Taylor expansion, then either the approximation is incorrect at low orders, or at higher orders there is an error ``dimensions too large''. So implementing your feature would require some extra effort.

Comment: See [the pgf manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), *Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Functions*: section 89.3 at the time of writing. There's a way to define your own functions too: see *Customizing the Mathematical Engine*, currently section 91.

Comment: @DavidR Yes, I've seen that. The problem is that the function is quite involved. There are more manageable expressions, like the one by Ramanujan, but they hold only under some approximations. Of course, one could cook up an approximate answer, but even this will require some effort. What one can do is to write `s(t) = a t + (b-a) sin^2(t) t`, where t is angle in radians, invert this, and plug it into the above code. But that's just some random approximation.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Done.

Comment: @percusse Amazing!

Answer (score 4):

It is a piece of cake in PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\xy{3*cos(t)|2*sin(t)}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-3,-2)(3,2)
\psparametricplot{0}{TwoPi}{\xy}
\pscurvepoints{0}{TwoPi}{\xy}{P}
\pspolylineticks[Ds=.5,ticksize=-5pt 0]{P}{ ds }{0}{20}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]