# How to draw a tangent of an elliptic curve on a fixed point

Tags: pgfplots

I need to draw a tangente of an elliptic curve on a fixed point, here is the code of the curve and the point, I don't know how to plot the tangente line.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        domain=-2.279018:3,      
        samples=201,
        smooth,   
        clip=false,
        % use same unit vectors on the axis
        axis equal image=true,
    ]

\addplot[blue] {sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)} node[right] {$E$};
\addplot[blue] {-sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)};

\begin{scriptsize}
    %== P ==
    \draw [fill=black] (-1.2,2.6) circle (2pt);
    \draw[color=black] (-1.4,2.7) node [left]{$P$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried using Geogebra, but instead of one tangente line, I have got 4 as shown on the picture
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to compute the derivative with a computer algebra system, and then to plot the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        scale only axis,
        axis lines=middle,
        domain=-2.279018:3,      
        samples=201,
        smooth,   
        clip=false,
        % use same unit vectors on the axis
        axis equal image=true,
    ]

\addplot[blue] {sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)} node[right] {$E$};
\addplot[blue] {-sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)};
\addplot[red] {2.621+0.251*(x+1.2)};


%\begin{scriptsize}
    %== P ==
    \draw [fill=black] (axis cs:-1.2,2.6) circle (2pt);
    \draw[color=black] (axis cs:-1.4,2.7) node [left]{$P$};
%\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @marmot, I thaught there was a specific Tangente function in Tikz.

Comment: @HindDev Honestly, I don't know if there is. Internally there must be some very powerful routines since Ti*k*z is able to draw perpendicular ticks, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403201/drawing-multiple-lines-perpendicular-on-an-ellipse-i-e-eyelashes-using-tikz/403211#403211).

Answer (score 4):

You can carry the derivative information with the node

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,ymax=5,
        xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},
        scale only axis, axis lines=middle,
        domain=-2.279018:3,
        samples=201,smooth,clip=false,
        axis equal image=true
    ]
\addplot[blue] {sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)} node[right] {$E$} 
    node[sloped,fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt,pos=0.27,label={[absolute]180:$P$}] (a) {};
\draw ($(a.west)!-2cm!(a.east)$) -- ($(a.west)!2cm!(a.east)$);
\addplot[blue] {-sqrt(x^3-3*x+5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you play with `pos` key the tangent walks with it. But keep in mind that

```
 \begin{scriptize}...\end{scriptsize}
```

has no effect in TikZ environment.

Answer (score 3):

A way to do it with MetaPost, for whom it may interest. MetaPost is able to figure out the tangent of a path upon a given point, thanks to its `direction` macro.

Integrated in a LuaLaTeX program for typesetting convenience.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85, luamplib}
    \mplibnumbersystem{double}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
% Macro creating a function graph
vardef function(expr xmin, xmax, xstep)(text f_x) =
    save x; x := xmin;
    (x, f_x) forever: hide(x := x + xstep) exitif x > xmax; .. (x, f_x) endfor
    if x - xstep < xmax: hide(x := xmax) .. (x, f_x) fi
enddef;
vardef f(expr x) = sqrt(x**3 - 3x + 5) enddef;
u = cm; xmin = -4; xmax = 5; xstep = .1; ymax = -ymin = 5; root = -2.279018;
path curve; curve = function(root, 3, xstep)(f(x));
% Tangent computation
beginfig(1);
    draw (reverse curve reflectedabout (origin, (1, 0)) .. curve) scaled u withcolor red; 
    x = -1.2; y = f(x); label.top("$P$", z*u);
    pair v; v = 2.5unitvector direction (x-root)/xstep of curve;
    drawdot z*u withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
    draw (z - v -- z + v) scaled u withcolor blue;
    draw ((x, 0) -- z) scaled u dashed evenly;
    label.bot("$" & decimal x & "$", (x*u, 0)); label.lrt("$O$", origin);
    drawarrow (xmin*u, 0) -- (xmax*u, 0); label.bot("$x$", (xmax*u, 0));
    drawarrow (0, ymin*u) -- (0, ymax*u); label.lft("$y$", (0, ymax*u));
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first-resort solution with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}


\newcommand\f{t|sqrt(t^3-3*t+5)}
\newcommand\g{t|-sqrt(t^3-3*t+5)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,plotpoints=150](-5.5,-5.5)(5.5,5.5)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-5,-5)(5,5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psparametricplot[linecolor=cyan,linewidth=2pt]{-2.279}{3}{\f}
\psparametricplot[linecolor=cyan,linewidth=2pt]{-2.279}{3}{\g}
\psplotTangent[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{-1.2}{3}{\f}
\curvepnode{-1.2}{\f}{P}
\multido{\i=-40+15}{4}{\rput(P){\pcline[nodesepB=-3,linecolor=green](3;\i)(0,0)}}
\pscircle*[linecolor=blue](P){2pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]